# Receive email with attachments

Tags: email

Is it possible to receive emails through the mail server functionality of Mathematica with email attachments?

Comment: File -> Send Mail

Answer (score 10):

I think you're looking for `MailItem` and its `"Attachments"` property.

Connect to a mailserver:

```
mail = MailServerConnect[]
```

Get the attachments of the last email:

```
mail["INBOX"][-1]["Attachments"]
```

More, but sparse, information is in the documentation for [`MailItem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MailItem.html).

It's important to note that Mathematica itself is not a mail server and doesn't have the ability to receive mail itself - it can only interact with an *existing* mail server via IMAP. That existing mail server is the thing that receives mail.